# Subset a shapefile that excludes certain field values by using NOT in Select by Attribute where clause

Tags: arcpy, sql, select-by-attribute, error-000358, where-clause

I am using ArcPy 2.7 to subset a shapefile. I am trying to use arcpy.Select_analysis to exclude certain features from a shapefile (idle fields denoted as 1401 in the field 'Crop_Type'. my 'Crop_Type' field is of type long.

I'm receiving the following error:
ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression  NOT "Crop_Type" = '1401'

Looking at [ESRI's Building a SQL Expression](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/building-a-query-expression.htm#GUID-EC06FE3F-38BA-4CF2-AEAF-F69D65C7C567), my code is:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput =  True

in_features = 'Copy_SaltonT4_2017.shp'
out_feature_class = 'CroppedFields.shp'
where_clause = 'NOT "Crop_Type" = \'1401\''

arcpy.Select_analysis(in_features, out_feature_class, where_clause)

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(in_features, out_feature_class)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes should only be used with string literal values.  Do not put single quotes around a long value.  Change the where_clause to the following:

```
where_clause = 'NOT "Crop_Type" = 1401'
```

Also this should work:

```
where_clause = '"Crop_Type" <> 1401'
```